# Reading a series of numbers from a file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I currently have a method that reads ints from a file and upon reaching 16 ints a regex is run against the string (register). Although the way the ints (or numbers) are read in from the file is causing me problems. It currently reads all of the numbers from a file and disregards any other chars such as letters. Hence the following would be collected:

Example.txt:

> h568fj34fj390fjkkkkf385837692g1234567891011121314fh

Incorrect output:

> 5683439038583769

Correct output:

> 1234567891011121

But I only want to collect a string of consecutive numbers (if there are other chars like letters inbetween the numbers they would not be counted) and the method would such for a series of numbers (16 in total) with no other chars like letters inbetween.

My current logic is as follows:

```
    var register = new StringBuilder();

    using(var stream = File.Open(readme.txt, FileMode.Open))
    {
                bool execEnd = false;
                bool fileEnded = false;

                int buffer;
                while(execEnd = true)
                {
                while(register.Length < 16 && !fileEnded)
                    {
                buffer = stream.ReadByte();
                if(buffer == -1)
                {
                fileEnded = true;
                break;
                }

     var myChar = (char)buffer;
     if(Char.IsNumber(myChar))
    register.Append(myChar);
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be your required Regex: `\d{16}`

So you could use LINQ to find all matches:

```
var allMatches = 
     System.IO.File.ReadLines(path)
    .Select(l => System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(l, @"\d{16}"))
    .Where(m => m.Success)
    .ToList();

foreach (var match in allMatches)
{
    String number = match.Value;
}
```

Comment: Hi , thanks, but its not in the register I need evaluating, its how the numbers get into the register string in the first place

Comment: @user1326461: I'm afraid i haven't understood anything. The LINQ query only selects lines with at least one matching number. If you don't want to select the `Match` but the String-Number directly, you just have to change the 4.line of my code to `.Where(m => m.Success).Select(m => m.Value)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = "h568fj34fj390fjkkkkf385837692g1234567891011121314fh";
string num = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(input, @"\d{16}").Value;
```